# Montgomery modular multiplication – confusion with subtraction of modulus

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic, montgomery-multiplication

I'm reading the paper “[COMPARISON OF SCALABLE MONTGOMERY MODULAR MULTIPLICATION IMPLEMENTATIONS EMBEDDED IN RECONFIGURABLE HARDWARE](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cbfd/5f286cf3a54025356cff90cd17ab083fafc1.pdf)” (PDF) on hardware algorithms for montgomery multiplication for modular exponentiation, and I'm confused as to how the standard radix-2 montgomery mulitplication algorithm (R2MM), and the multiple-word radix-2 montgomery multiplication algorithm (MWR2MM) differ with regards to the final subtraction of the modulus.

**The standard algorithm is as follows:**

$\newcommand{\newkeyword}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{\mathrm{#2}}}%
\newkeyword{\for}{for}%
\newkeyword{\to}{to}%
\newkeyword{\loop}{loop}%
\newkeyword{\if}{if}%
\newkeyword{\then}{then}%
\newkeyword{\else}{else}%
\newkeyword{\end}{end}%
S_0 := 0\\
\for\ i:=0\ \to\ (m-1)\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ q_i := (S_i + x_iY) \bmod 2\\
\ \ \ \ \if\ (q_i=1)\ \then\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_{i+1} := (S_i + x_iY + M)/2\\
\ \ \ \ \else\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_{i+1} := (S_i + x_iY)/2\\
\ \ \ \ \end\ \if\\
\end\ \for\\
\if\ (S_m \geq M)\ \then\\
\ \ \ \ S_m:=S_m-M\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{// the final correction step}\\
\end\ \if\\
Z:=S_m\\
$

where:

- $\\S$ is the result
- $M$ is the modulus
- $Y$ is the multiplicand
- $X$ is the multiplier and $x_i$ is the single bit (e.g. $X =

**The MWR2MM_CSA algorithm is as follows**

$
S = 0\\  
\for\ i=0\  \to\ (m-1)\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ (C,S^{(0)}) := x_i\cdot Y^{(0)}+S^{(0)}\\
\ \ \ \ \if\ S^{(0)}_{0} = 1\ \then\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (C,S^{(0)}) := (C,S^{(0)}) + M^{(0)}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \for\ j = 1\ \to\ e-1\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (C,S^{(j)}) := C+ x_i \cdot Y^{(j)} + M^{(j)} + S^{(j)}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S^{(j-1)} := (S_0^{(j)},S^{(j-1)}_{w-1..1}) \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \end\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S^{(e-1)} := (C,S^{(e-1)}_{w-1..1})\\
\ \ \ \ \else\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \for\ j := 1\ \to\ e-1\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (C,S^{(j)}) := C+ x_i \cdot Y^{(j)} +  S^{(j)}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S^{(j-1)} := (S_0^{(j)},S^{(j-1)}_{w-1..1}) \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \end\ \loop\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S^{(e-1)} := (C,S^{(e-1)}_{w-1..1})\\
\ \ \ \ \end\ \if\\
\end\ \loop\\
$

where:

- $\\S$ is the result
- $M$ is the modulus
- $Y$ is the multiplicand
- $X$ is the multiplier and $x_i$ is the single bit (e.g. $X = (x_n,...,x_1,x_0)$.
- The superscript are the words vectors (e.g. $M = (0,M^{e-1},...,M^1,M^0)$
- $(A,B)$ is the concatenation of two bit vectors.
- $m$ is the total bit-width of the operands (2048, in my case)
- $w$ is the width of choosen words
- $e$ is the number of words of bit-width $w$ required to complete the vectors ($e = \lceil(m+1)/w\rceil$

This result is only guaranteed to be in the range of $0<S<2M$, so there is the possibility of needing a final subtraction

The paper states that, in the standard algorithm,

> In typical applications (e.g. RSA, ECC), input operands X , Y are
>   transformed into Montgomery domain by pre-multiplication with a factor
>   $2^{2m}\bmod M$. The final MM with value ($A = \mathit{MM} (A, 1)$ in the
>   exponentiation algorithm) makes the final result smaller than M
>   (without any final correction) and provides the result $XY \bmod M$.

My questions are therefore:

1. If you don't subtract the modulus from R2MM result, then the results of both R2MM and MWR2MM should be identical, right?
2. If you premultiply both algorithms' input by  $2^{2m} \bmod M$, then the results should still be the same (no final subtraction needed) right?

I ask this because my results do not seem to support this, and I find myself needing to perform subtraction regardless of premultiplication.